# how to install older version of kivy in python

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Python 3.6.2 and at the moment i use Kivy 1.10.0 but I need to use Kivy 1.9.1. I have tried to install it through pip but it shows me an error.

> building 'kivy._event' extension
>        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools":
>   http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Did something change from kivy 1.9.1 to 1.10.0? I can install 1.10 without any problems with pip.

Comment: You should download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kivy/1.9.1. Then follow this guide https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html

Comment: The might be no matching binary wheels for the older version on pypi. So it is using the source version and tries to compile it. You will BTW get a sililar effect when using an old version of pip.

Comment: I'm curious about why you need to use the older version, there shouldn't be any reason to want to do that, did we break some api you depend on?

Comment: I want to install Kivy Designer but it doesnt start.

Comment: Ok, then i want to warn you that kivy designer is not a complete or stable software, people seem to stop wanting it after they understand kv, so i would advise you to focus on that instead (and installing an older version of kivy is certainly not a solution).

Comment: Yes actually i have thought of that already....I will stop trying with kivy designer and focus on learning kv instead.